# submodules of a group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-rings

Estoy viendo el álgebra de grupo $KG$ donde $K$ un cuerpo y $G$ un grupo finito. Definimos $KG=\left\{{\sum_{g\in{G}}^{}k_gg : k_g\in{K}, g\in{G}}\right\}$ y la llamamos álgebra de grupo. $KG$ es un $K$-ev con base $G$. LUEGO la $\dim(KG)=|G|$. $KG$ es una álgebra sobre $K$. También $KG$ es un $KG$-módulo de diferentes maneras.

Ejemplo: Sea $G=C_3=\left\{{1,g,g^2}\right\}$.
Quiero hallar todos los A-submódulos de A, donde $A=\mathbb{F_2}C_3$.
Tenemos que $\mathbb{F_2}C_3=\left\{{0,1,g,g^2,1+g,1+g^2,g+g^2,1+g+g^2}\right\}$. Espero alguna sugerencia.

---

**English translation:**

I am looking at the group algebra $KG$ where $K$ is a field and $G$ a finite group. We define $KG=\left\{{\sum_{g\in{G}}^{}k_gg : k_g\in{K}, g\in{G}}\right\}$ and call it the *group algebra*. $KG$ is a vector space with basis $G$. Thus $\text{dim}(KG) = |G|$. $KG$ is an algebra over $K$. Also, $KG$ is a $KG$-module in different ways.

Example: Let $G=C_3=\left\{{1,g,g^2}\right\}$. I want to find all the $A$-submodules of $A$, where $A=\mathbb{F_2}C_3$. We have that $\mathbb{F_2}C_3=\left\{{0,1,g,g^2,1+g,1+g^2,g+g^2,1+g+g^2}\right\}$.

I would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please questions in English